# svn remove file included in commit by mistake

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I commited changes to a few files, one of which was commited by mistake. I want to revert it to its previous state, keeping the changes to the others.
How do I do that as cleanly as possible (least possible number of commits to the repository)?

Comment: The correct approach would be to **entirely** revert the commit and commit it again but without mistakes.

Comment: Less number of commits is not the best criteria. To do so you'd need to restore the repository from a backup copy and instruct all developers to revert their working copies to an earlier revision and remove whatever caches apply (e.g. IDE or TortoiseSVN): an unnecessary and potentially dangerous mess.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yeah I've realized that I handn't chosen the best criteria to evaluate the solution, @ bahrep and reverted the commit entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you right-click the file in question and select "TortoiseSVN->Show Log". Then select the revision you want to revert (left click), select the path of your file , right-click to your file in Path section of "Show Log"-dialog and select "Revert changes from this file"

Then you need to commit(it is good practice to note the revision number you reverted into the commit message )